# Referencing a global hash from Puppet DSL

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to reference a global hash from a Puppet DSL manifest, but `scope.lookupvar` is failing to find it.

My declaration is in `rubydefs.pp` and is of the form

```
$my_hash = JSON.parse(`...some stuff that spits out JSON...`)
```

I use this hash in my templates with no trouble.

In my DSL file `mymodule.rb` I try to reference the hash like this:

```
foo = scope.lookupvar('::my_hash')
foo.keys.each do |i|
...
```

but `foo` always ends up undefined.  I've tried just `'my_hash'` (without the `::`) with the same result.  This is the error message from the puppet agent:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `keys' for :undefined:Symbol ....
```

I'm definitely including the files in the right order; my `site.pp` looks like

```
import "rubydefs.pp"
...
node mynode {
    include mymodule
}
```

How can I reference this hash from a Puppet DSL file?

Comment: According to the FAQ at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/faq.html#why-does-puppet-have-its-own-language using the Ruby DSL is not an entirely safe thing to do. Do you really need to? Note that in Puppet 4 (or Puppet 3.x with the `parser=future` option) you can iterate arrays and hashes inside the Puppet DSL.

Comment: Also, the Ruby DSL is now deprecated according to this post from a Puppet Labs developer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/3lD1tChZQJw/T8NEaDJW8t8J

Comment: Thanks for that -- `parser=future` is a good pointer.